# How can I commit a message offset to Kafka topic after consumption?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

It seems that the offset is not being committed.

I am using kafka Python package. This is my code

```py
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'quickstart-events',
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='my-group',
    auto_commit_interval_ms=1000,
)

msg_pack = consumer.poll(max_records=10,timeout_ms=500,update_offsets=True)
for tp,messages in msg_pack.items():
    for message in messages:
        print("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (tp.topic, tp.partition,
                                             message.offset, message.key,
                                             message.value))
```

But the problem is I always get all the messages from the starting. Sometimes I don't get any. Can you please help me?

```
quickstart-events:0:52: key=None value=b'1'
quickstart-events:0:53: key=None value=b'2'
quickstart-events:0:54: key=None value=b'3'
quickstart-events:0:55: key=None value=b'4'
quickstart-events:0:56: key=None value=b'5'
quickstart-events:0:57: key=None value=b'1'
quickstart-events:0:58: key=None value=b'2'
quickstart-events:0:59: key=None value=b'3'
quickstart-events:0:60: key=None value=b'4'
quickstart-events:0:61: key=None value=b'5'
```

Comment: I would reword your question to a Kafka only question as it involves no aspect of AWS or unique aspect of SQS

Comment: Kafka and SQS are not really equivalent. It's hard to tell what you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I always get all the messages from the starting.

This should only happen once, based on these

```
auto_offset_reset='earliest',
enable_auto_commit=True,
group_id='my-group',
```

> Sometimes I don't get any

Then you might have no lag in the consumer group (no records to consume). You'd need to use `kafka-consumer-groups --describe --group my-group` to check the lag or that offsets are getting committed in the way you expect.

If offsets aren't committed in the way you expect, then you should disable auto commits and do it manually

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it does not work. Can you please edit how we can update the offset after each message is processed?

Comment: What doesn't work? `kafka-consumer-groups` CLI? Have you tried calling [`consumer.commit`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.commit) within the loop?

Comment: Yeah , i tried adding the `consumer.commit()` inside the loop. It works Thanks